# Google Sheets INvenotry Tracker Jump to item

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to help a friend create a google sheet to track his store inventory.  We have a few barcode scanners we are using to add inventory to the sheet.

What we want to be able to do is have a specific cell selected, scan an item barcode and if that barcode exists in the spreadsheet (column A specifically), jump to that row where the item exists so that we can either add more to the inventory on the floor or warehouse, or subtract it from inventory.

Bonus feature we would like, if the item does not exist to be able to just jump to the very end of the spreadsheet so that we can add it as a new item.

lots of research and can't find anything specifically to do this.  Can use Vlookup but cant figure out how to get it to work exactly how we want or it if even will.

Comment: Greetings. With the greatest respect, I am having problems understanding your question. Would you please explain EXACTLY what is your problem?

Comment: We have an inventory sheet, to simplify what we need this is how we want it to work.

Column A starts with row 4.  It would have the barcode of an item, column b would have the name.

We want to have column A row 1 be a search box.  When we scan something with the barcode scanner ir would input the number from the barcode, then search the rest of column A.  If it finds the same barcode jump to that row, if it does not, it jumps to the end for us to add a new item.

Comment: Your solution involves a script and StackOverflow is not a bespoke scripting service. The first issue is compatibility of your scanner: have you read Google's help on [Use a barcode scanner](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10106618) or the support question on [Creating a script for barcode reader time entry](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/24387480/creating-a-script-for-barcode-reader-time-entry?hl=en)? I suggest that you focus on getting your scanner to work with Forms and Sheets and then ask a new question if you still need help.

Comment: It is already working with sheets.  So the question does not change.

We are simply trying to make things easer.  We can scan with the reader and it will put the numbers in the sheet.  We are just trying to make it look for the number it gets from the barcode.  

Currently we just ctrl+f and bring up the find box on google sheets and do it that way.  If it does not find it we manually just go to the end of the sheet and add the entry.

But we have to scan in over 10k different barcodes, so the easier we can make it the better.

Comment: "we have to scan in over 10k different barcodes" Just to clarify... you are consolidating inventory systems and you have a record of inventory consisting of 10K items/barcodes and you propose to each barcode one-at-a-time. This is inconceivable. **Are you saying you don't have a digital record of those barcodes, associated data including stock quantity?** A phased approach would be more logical; 1) import the barcodes; 2) run a script to find matches with your existing stock; 3) update values/records as appropriate. (qty is not the only relevant value, what about the cost and sell prices)?

Comment: We are a retro toy and funko pop store.  The inventory mostly comes from funko pops.  They have barcodes but we buy secondhand and resale them.  We do not need prices because the prices change on a daily basis from being collectibles.  We use an app to determine prices so the price technically comes from the barcode, but it can change daily and we have to scan the barcode to get the price of the item.  They can fluctuate anywhere from a buck to 50 bucks in a day.

Comment: So the goal is to just get an inventory of the items we have, more so that we can quickly search an item, see if we have it or not.  The whole situation is not a normal retail store situation.  We have the manpower to get everything scanned in and then keep it scanned in going forward.  Just trying to make t as easy as possible on the people scanning them all in.

Answer (score 1):

A installable `onEdit` trigger should be created for this script.

```
function findBarcode(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  // Search code is entered in Cell A1
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === sheetName && e.range.rowStart === 1 && e.range.columnStart === 1){
    // searchTerm is in cell A1 of Sheet1
    // barcodes start in row4
    // get existing barcodes and descriptions
    var dataColA = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues()

    // search for match, result is zero-based, so row = result+1
    var searchResult = dataColA.map(r => r[0]).indexOf(dataColA[0][0],2) 
    if (searchResult != -1){
      // match is found, jump to row
      sheet.getRange((searchResult+1),1).activateAsCurrentCell()
    }
    else{
      // match is NOT found
      // paste searchTerm to last row, move cursor to row/adjacent column
      var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
      sheet.getRange((lr+1),1).setValue(dataColA[0][0])
      sheet.getRange((lr+1),2).activateAsCurrentCell()
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Sample**

[image: snapshot]